# How to Tokenize group of words in Python

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I am developing a application in python which gives job recommendation based on the resume uploaded. I am trying to tokenize resume before processing further. I want to tokenize group of words. For example **Data Science** is a keyword when i tokenize i will get **data** and **science** separately. How to overcome this situation. Is there any library which does these extraction in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking to generate [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) (bi-grams in particular). If that's the case, the following is one way to achieve this:

```
from nltk import ngrams
resume = '... working in the data science field for years ...'
n = 2
bigrams = ngrams(resume.split(), n)
for grams in bigrams:
  print grams
```

Comment: thank you, this way i can get combination of words .

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to tokenise all the words in the resume by some delimiter such as a space then based on your example input "Data Science" and output ["data", "science"] the following function will lower case a string an split its contents by a space, returning a list of strings.

```
def tokenize(resume_string):
    return resume_string.lower().split(" ")
```

Comment: Nikesh, did this address your problem sufficiently?